# First Python/Kivy/KivyMD App. Unable to save data from textfield to variable + data binding to MDList

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I recently started to work on a school turn in app in python/kivy.
I'm at the state where I created and UI in kivymd and a user class.
I want to save the info into a list of user objects but **I get a KeyError: 'firstname' error message.
Do you guys know what can be the problem?**

**Also what I want to implement, is that I put a MDList to the second screen. With Data Binding I want to show the First and Last names of the users that are in the list. Any idea how can I achive that? I didn't find and usable solutions on the web.**

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import _textinput_list

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    id: smn
    AddUserScreen:
    ViewListScreen:
    ModifyUser:
    
<AddUserScreen>:
    id: screen1
    name: 'adduser'
    MDTextField:
        id:firstname
        hint_text: "First Name"
        helper_text: "Please enter your firts name"
        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.9}
        size_hint_x: None
        width:300
    MDTextField:
        id: lastname
        hint_text: "Last Name"
        helper_text: "Please enter your last name"
        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8}
        size_hint_x: None
        width:300
    MDTextField:
        id: city
        hint_text: "City of Residence"
        helper_text: "Please enter your city of residence"
        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}
        size_hint_x: None
        width:300 
    MDTextField:
        id: year
        hint_text: "Birthyear"
        helper_text: "Please enter your birthyear"
        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
        size_hint_x: None
        width:300               
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'View User List'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'viewlists'        
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Add User'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_press: root.addUser()
        
        
<ViewListScreen>:
    id: screen2
    name: 'viewlists'
    MDList:
        id: container
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.9}
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Add New User'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'adduser'       
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Modify User'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'modify'

<ModifyUser>:
    id: 'screen3"
    name: 'modify'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Add New User'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'adduser'       
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'View User'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'viewlists'
        
"""


class AddUserScreen(Screen):
    def addUser(self):
        screen1_instance = sm.get_screen('adduser')
        firstname1 = screen1_instance.ids['firstname'].text
        lastname1 = screen1_instance.ids['lastname'].text
        city1 = screen1_instance.ids['city'].text
        year1 = screen1_instance.ids['year'].text
        userlist.append(User(firstname1, lastname1, city1, year1))
        print('New User Added')


class ViewListScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ModifyUser(Screen):
    pass


userlist = []
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(AddUserScreen(name='adduser'))
sm.add_widget(ViewListScreen(name='viewlists'))
sm.add_widget(ModifyUser(name='modify'))


class App(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen


App().run()


class User:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, country, year):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.country = country
        self.year = year
```

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your code. First, the lines:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(AddUserScreen(name='adduser'))
sm.add_widget(ViewListScreen(name='viewlists'))
sm.add_widget(ModifyUser(name='modify'))
```

are building a widget tree that is not used in your `App`. These lines can be removed.

Second, the `User` class definition appears after the `App().run()`, which means that the running `App` does not have that class available. This class definition should be moved before the `App().run()`

Third, the `addUser()` method uses the `sm` defined above, which is not part of your `App` widget tree, has not been displayed, and therefore, has no `ids` (causing the error). A correction to the `addUser()` method accesses the actual widget tree of the `App`. Like this:

```
class AddUserScreen(Screen):
    def addUser(self):
        screen1_instance = self.manager.get_screen('adduser')  # get correct Screen
        firstname1 = screen1_instance.ids['firstname'].text
        lastname1 = screen1_instance.ids['lastname'].text
        city1 = screen1_instance.ids['city'].text
        year1 = screen1_instance.ids['year'].text
        userlist.append(User(firstname1, lastname1, city1, year1))
        print('New User Added')
```

Also, naming your `App` as `App` is probably a bad idea, as `App` is the name of the base class of `MDApp`. A better idea is to choose a name that is unique.